# Create multiple VMs using ansible module vmware_guest

Tags: ansible, vmware

Trying to create multiple VMs using ansible module vmware_guest.
I am getting error

```
"msg": "with_dict expects a dict"
 "failed": true
```

I am using myvars.yml content as under:

```
---
myvms:
   violet:
     - vmhost: violet-vm
       vmip: 192.168.1.163
   yellow:
      - vmhost: yellow-vm
        vmip: 192.168.1.164
```

My task file vmspin.yml is:

```
- name: create the VM
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars_files:
  - myvars.yml
  tasks:
  - vmware_guest:
      hostname: "myhost"
      username: "administrator@vsphere.local"
      password: "password"
      datacenter: dc1     
      name: 
      - name: "{{item.value.vmhost}}"   
      disk:
      - size_gb: 4
        type: thin
        datastore: Datastore1          
      networks:
      - name: VM Network
        ip: "{{item.value.vmip}}"
        netmask: 255.255.255.0
      template: rhel7_base_template    
    with_dict:
      - "{{myvms}}"
    register: deploy
```

Any solution

Comment: My myvars.yml should be as under but problem persists
---
myvms:
   violet:
     vmhost: violet-vm
     vmip: 192.168.1.163
   yellow:
     vmhost: yellow-vm
     vmip: 192.168.1.164

Answer (score 1):

By saying:

```
with_dict:
  - "{{myvms}}"
```

you pass a list with single element that contains your `myvms` dict into lookup.

Replace it with just:

```
with_dict: "{{ myvms }}"
```

Comment: with_dict: "{{ myvms }}" has not helped. Error remains the same.

Comment: Not possible. Either your didn't save your changes, or the error is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must delete "-" in you varibles files:

### not:

```
myvms:
   violet:
     - vmhost: violet-vm
       vmip: 192.168.1.163
   yellow:
      - vmhost: yellow-vm
        vmip: 192.168.1.164
```

but:

---

```
myvms:
   violet:
     vmhost: violet-vm
     vmip: 192.168.1.163
   yellow:
     vmhost: yellow-vm
     vmip: 192.168.1.164
```